# line traversal in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am doing a file traversal in awk. An example of this is

```
Dat time range column session - 1
time name place session animal - 2 
hi bye name things - 3
```

In both of these . I need to traverse line by line and in I need to traverse word by word in the line that contains `session` .

Thus in this case I need to reach line 1 and 2 as it contains the word session and not line 3 as it doesn't contain that field(In the sense I can skip this). From there I need to traverse word by word to reach the session field .

I know `$0` can represent the whole line. But my question is how to traverse word by word after reaching the line.

Could you please help me regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the current line `$0` with this construct:

```
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i
```

this makes use of the predefined awk variable `NF` which stands for the number of fields on the current line (`$0`).

You can examine the value of `$i` as it iterates through the line and based on that determine what to do with the value. E.g, print it, skip it, etc. `if ($i == "session") ...`

Update:

You can also use the `match()` function to determine if the current line you are processing contains the "session" string without iterating through the line. E.g.,

```
where = match($0, "session")
if (where > 0)
   print "Found session in this line";
else
   print "session not found in this line";
```

Note that `match()` takes a regular expression as the 2nd parameter, so your matches can be quite sophisticated.  See this page for more information about this function and other [awk string functions](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html).

Comment: @User, make sure you upvote/accept the answers that helped solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop, filtering only on the lines that contain "session":

```
awk '/session/{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { \
                  if ($i == "session") \
                    do_whatever_here \
                } \
              }'
```

You can read more on these instructions here: [`for`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_74.html), [string comparison](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_61.html) and [`if`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_71.html).

Comment: Redundant use of grep.  Don't do this.

Comment: Indeed: `awk '/session/ {for ...}' your_file`. Also you can remove the un-needed line continuations.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks. I'm just learning `awk` actually. The `\\` was there assuming this is written in a terminal (rather than script).